# Interop is missing from my Reference Manager

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, winforms, assembly-references

I've copied a Visual Studio project from a Windows 10 computer to my Windows 7 machine. The sulution cannot be compiled because of an invalid assembly reference. On the original machine, the reference manager looks like this:

[image]

while on my machine the assemblies starting witn "interop" are missing:

[image]

What should I install on my computer to have interop.SQLXMLBULKLOADLib assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the SqlXml 3.0 Service Pack 3, you can download it [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11811).

Comment: Yes this was the solution, thank you. The reference in the original project was wrong. The correctly installed SQLXMLBULKLOADLib  3.0 (or 4,0) Type Library appears among the COM components, not under Assemblies/Extensions.